# ERROR problem with a function. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

In function Determininant i keep getting an error....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int maxsize = 10;

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

void transpose (double omatrix[][maxsize],double tmatrix [][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
        {
            tmatrix[j][i] = omatrix[i][j];
        }


    }
}

void sub (double omatrix[][maxsize], double smatrix[][maxsize], int array_size, int i, int j)
{
    int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < array_size; a++)
    {
        if (a != i)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < array_size; b++)
            {
                if (b != j)
                {
                    smatrix[counter1][counter2] = omatrix[a][b];
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
            counter1++;
        }
    }
}

double Determininant(double original_matrix[][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    if(array_size == 1)
        return original_matrix[0][0];
    else if(array_size == 2)
        return original_matrix[0][0] * original_matrix[1][1] - original_matrix[0][1] * original_matrix[1][0];
    double d = 0.0;
    double temp[maxsize][maxsize];
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        sub (original_matrix,temp,array_size, 0, i);
        d += pow(-1.0,i) * original_matrix[0][i] * d(temp, array_size - 1);
    }
    return d;
}

void print (const double m[][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
                {
                    fout << m[i][j] << "  ";
                }
                fout << "\n";
            }
            fout << "\n";
}
```

The error is error: 'd' cannot be used as a function.
Any ideas on whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what the error message says: `d` is a `double` and you can't call it as a function. Perhaps you meant `Determinant(temp, array_size - 1)`?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what was wrong. It just took someone else to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's the end of this line:

```
d += pow(-1.0,i) * original_matrix[0][i] * d(temp, array_size - 1);
```

As casablanca said, do you mean this?:

```
d += pow(-1.0,i) * original_matrix[0][i] * Determinant(temp, array_size - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d += pow(-1.0,i) * original_matrix[0][i] * d(temp, array_size - 1);
```

The clause `d(temp, array_size - 1)` is telling C++ to call function d.